# How to do flash fullscreen in facebook application?

Tags: flash, facebook, fullscreen

Farmvilli can do fullscreen.
HappyIsland can do fullscreen.

But what is the trick to enable flash fullscreen in facebook application?

Comment: Evert, fb:swf blocked full screen flash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I have found the solution.

1. you must not use fb:swf
2. you will have to use fb:iframe to contain a html page that loads the flash (by swfobject or etc).
3. you will have to set the flash param "allowFullScreen" to true.
4. put the code

   stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

inside MouseEvent / keyboard event functions, so the full screen code is triggered by user interaction.